# Trying to make a Navigation Drawer that doesn't overlap another view

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make an app that has a sidebar (a linear layout, for now; it would be a sort of actionbar) on the left with some buttons that, when clicked, open the navigation drawer, which, when fully opened, should be to the right of the sidebar. The problem is that the drawer overlaps anything else. how do I prevent it?
also, how do I make the drawer start from the right side of the sidebar instead of from the left side of the screen? otherwise part of its contents would be hidden by the sidebar.

Is this impossible to do with the drawer? Am I forced to use a SlidingPanelLayout? I searched all over the internet but found nothing.

here's the activity's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sideBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:minWidth="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_menu1"
                android:minWidth="30dip"
                android:minHeight="30dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <!-- the main view of the activity -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/normalList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white" >
        </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- the drawer's list -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the single items of both lists:

```
<!-- this is for the drawer -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drwrimg"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icondescription"
    android:src="@drawable/item"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/drwrtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/drwrimg"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/drwrcounter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color" />

</RelativeLayout>


<!-- and this for the main list -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/filesListDrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="2dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icondescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberOfFiles"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

an image of the sidebar how it is now:

[image: situation]

and how I want it to be:

[image: aim]

**EDIT #2**: made the question more clear.

**EDIT #3**: clarified even more and added images, also to show the desired result.

Comment: please post a link to the image

Comment: done. I thought that I wouldn't be allowed to post links, either, with such low reputation, but I suppose I should have tried anyway...